# Creating a separate image for boot partition in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto Linux image with two partitions: boot and rootfs.

I would like to create two separate images: one with rootfs and the second one with bootstrap and u-boot files. I have two questions about it.

1. Is there a better way to do it than creating two separate `.bb` files for my images and two separate `.wks` files - one `.wks` file with partition rootfs and the second one with boot partition?
2. Is it possible to create  in Yocto image files with extension `.img` instead of, for example, `.wic`?

Comment: I think it's no rocket science to extract the partition images from the wks files. And if I remember correctly, the partitions will be placed in the `deploy/xxx` folder anyhow as `rootfs-timestamp.ext4.gz` or something like that.